# How to show all variation prices on Shop Page?

Tags: woocommerce

I have products with variations, and each variation has a different price.

Right now I have the product with the minimum variation price showing like this:

```
--------
|  **  |
|  **  |
--------
The orange box
From: 99$
```

What I want is this:

```
--------
|  **  |
|  **  |
--------
The orange box
Lite: 99$
Standard: 109$
Deluxe: 199$
```

**New info:**

With the help of [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-radio-buttons/) plugin, and editing it I have managed to get to this point:

```
--------
|  **  |
|  **  |
--------
The orange box
Lite: 
Standard: 
Deluxe:
```

But I'm, still missing the variation prices and there seems to be no documentation or implemented methods to get them easily.

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing really, I'm not familiar with the wordpress architecture. I'm reading documentation at this moment but still no solution.

Comment: @Dez I am closer now but still can't find how to get the prices.